# Nx Angular: TypeError: import_chart.registerables is not iterable

Tags: angular, jestjs, ng2-charts

I have got this error in jest with ng2-charts:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: import_chart.registerables is not iterable (cannot read property undefined)

      1 | import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
      2 | import { ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
    > 3 | import { ThemeService } from 'ng2-charts';
        | ^
      4 |
      5 | type Theme = 'light-theme' | 'dark-theme';
      6 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs:257:7)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../libs/core/src/lib/utils/theme/ng2-chart.service.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../libs/core/src/index.ts:6:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/features/dashboard/dashboard.component.spec.ts:10:1)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (../../node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (../../node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
      at _run10000 (../../node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
      at runCLI (../../node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)
```

My app uses jest for testing and the configuration file is:

```
/* eslint-disable */
export default {
    displayName: 'core',
    preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
            stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
        },
    },
    coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/libs/core',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$|lodash-es)'],
    snapshotSerializers: [
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
    ],
};
```

I have got the error after putting lodash-es to jest config, and
I have to keep the same configs.
This error came after my issue with [Angular in Nx](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/11888)